# Should statically-linked server binaries (daemons) be deemed more secure?

Tags: webserver, ssh, server, nginx

For a long time I've pondered this question. I am aware of the benefits and downsides of dynamic libraries (shared objects), including the [infamous article by Drepper](http://web.archive.org/web/20080612143346/http://people.redhat.com/drepper/no_static_linking.html).

All other things being equal, isn't a statically linked binary of, say Nginx or OpenSSH, less prone to stuff like library placement or other (non-kernel) attack vectors usually used by attackers?

Comment: It makes servicing components more difficult. Software that statically linked against vulnerable versions of OpenSSL will remain so until the software is updated, as opposed to just patching the server.

Comment: @vcsjones: couldn't you conversely state the same for dynamically linked binaries? As long as there is no update, both are vulnerable. Once there is an update, the only real downside seems to be the compilation time, no? But does the security increase in this scenario ("All other things being equal")?

Comment: You need to provide a measure or goal for "less prone" to attack vectors. By number of attacks, type, severity, consequence, remediation cost, etc.

Answer (score 4):

From a security standpoint, static linkage has one advantage and one weakness:

The advantage is that a statically-linked binary is immune to library injection attacks.

The weakness is that it cannot be protected by [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization): the address layout was determined at link time, so the OS is unable to randomize the location of executable code.

Library injection requires local access, while known-address attacks tend to be remote, so on the whole, I'd say that static linkage of server binaries is a net negative to security, in addition to its other drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting point. But why wouldn't I be able to compile my code with `-fPIC` to enable ASLR? I understand it would perhaps not be enabled by default, but shouldn't that suffice.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, -fPIC only applies to dynamic-library code.  You might be thinking of -fPIE, but that just permits the executable's base address to change.  Relative jumps still have the same offsets.